# \calstable top row of 2-row thead no text

Tags: tables, cals

I've created a LaTeX (xelatex compiled) table with `\cals` package, specifically, using `\calstable` command. I'm using R's RMD file to compile LaTeX to PDF. However, I'm using two rows for a nested `\thead{}` command with an intermediate .tex similar to the following:

```
%example.tex file

\documentclass[]{article}

% package load
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% initialize @ symbol
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

% begin custom commands
\newcommand\cellVtop[1]{
  \cell{#1}} 

\newcommand\cellVbot[1]{
  \cell{\vfill #1}}

\newcommand{\rrBoxGrantee}[1]{
  \parbox{2.5in}{\raggedright #1}}

\newcommand{\rrBoxFiveCol}[1]{
  \parbox{1in}{\raggedright #1}}

\newcommand{\rrBox}[1]{
  \parbox{0.875in}{\raggedright #1}}
% end custom commands    

\colwidths{{0.5in}{2.75in}{1.08333333333333in}{1.08333333333333in}{1.08333333333333in}}
\small
\begin{calstable}

\thead{
  \brow
    \nullcell{ltr}
    \spancontent{}
    \nullcell{ltr}
    \spancontent{}
    \nullcell{ltb}
    \nullcell{tb}
    \nullcell{trb}
    \alignC\spancontent{\vfill \textbf{Enrollees}}
  \erow
  \brow
    \alignC\cellVbot{\rrBox{\textbf{Rank}}}
    \alignL\cellVbot{\rrBox{\textbf{Grantee}}}
    \alignL\cellVbot{\rrBoxFiveCol{\textbf{Target}}}
    \alignL\cellVbot{\rrBoxFiveCol{\textbf{Actual}}}
    \alignL\cellVbot{\rrBoxFiveCol{\textbf{Percentage of Target}}}
\erow}

% begin multiple rows [...]
% repeat code for the below row until page break occurs (~30 rows)
\brow
  \alignL\cellVtop{0}
  \alignL\cellVtop{\rrBoxGrantee{Grantee A}}
  \alignL\cellVtop{0}
  \alignL\cellVtop{0}
  \alignL\cellVtop{0\%}
\erow
% end multiple rows [...]

\normalsize
\end{calstable}
\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

With, `[...]` representing excluded text for brevity.

However, when compiled, any table that runs to a next page is missing the header text of only the top-row of the `\thead`. The strange thing is that cell formatting is correct, just no text. It does seem that when there are no calls to `\nullcell{}` and `\spancontent`, that the columns are repeated as expected. However, I need the top header with "Enrollees" included to be merged as pictured below.

Am I missing a setting for printing both `\thead` rows or is this a bug?
[image]

P.S. I've confirmed that the example.tex file, above, can be compiled to .pdf via the following command in command prompt:
`xelatex example.tex`

Comment: This can't be compiled even adding a minimal preamble. For instance, `\cellVbot` is undefined. And there are errors anyway.

Comment: No, sorry. You lack a `\documentclass` declaration and `[...]` should either be expanded if they're useful to show the issue, or removed,.

Comment: Thanks again. I've addressed the issues that you've listed in edits to my question above. Please continue to inform me if there is an integral piece that I've left out that compilation requires. Note that I've placed the `[...]` so that the code for that row can be repeated until a page break is required. The page break is where the issue is occurring.

Comment: Sorry, I see just one page and no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for trying. However, as stated in the code I've outlined, above, the middle rows surrounded by `[...]` need to be repeated at least 30 times to introduce a page break. imo, it doesn't make sense to expand 30 rows in sample code since this can be done manually before executing the code via copy and paste 30 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is not lost, it's just too far right off the page. Spanning setup is a complicated thing which can go wrong. For each span, there should be one and only one "spancontent", but your code has several. To fix:

```
\thead{
  \brow
    \nullcell{ltr}
    %\spancontent{}  % FIXED
    \nullcell{ltr}
    %\spancontent{}  % FIXED
    \nullcell{ltb}
    \nullcell{tb}
    \nullcell{trb}
    \alignC\spancontent{\vfill \textbf{Enrollees}}
  \erow
  \brow
    \alignC\cellVbot{\rrBox{\textbf{Rank}}}
    \alignL\cellVbot{\rrBox{\textbf{Grantee}}}
    \alignL\cellVbot{\rrBoxFiveCol{\textbf{Target}}}
    \alignL\cellVbot{\rrBoxFiveCol{\textbf{Actual}}}
    \alignL\cellVbot{\rrBoxFiveCol{\textbf{Percentage of Target}}}
\erow}
```

Comment: Thanks you! This fixed my issue and my PDF now looks as expected. I was definitely overusing the `/spancontent{}` command. It seems from your comment, the command is only needed when adding content to a `/span` equivalent such as `nullcell{}`.